# Проверка открытия письма пользователем

Tags: php, email

В письмо вшита картинка logo_.png, при открытии письма-идет обращение за этой картинкой,обращение ловиться ReWriteRules и перенаправляя обращение к скрипту,куда передается часть имени картинки .там делается дело и потом выдает шаблонный файл logo.png(1х1 рх,прозрачная).

Так вот.тестировал на бесплатном хосте-все отлично работает,перенес на сайт.письмо открываешь-ничего не происходит(картинка прогружается).

Копируешь src картинки-открываешь через браузер-все отлично.что за бойда?

Comment: картинка продолжает грузиться с бесплатного хостинга? Но картинка в большинстве случаев даже не будет грузиться - так как по дефолту у многих выключена подгрузка картинок с сторонних урлов.

Comment: @KoVadim,тестировал с бесплатного-грузилось отлично.сейчас с платного-не работает нихрена

Comment: точно правило апача добавили? Возможно, эта картинка кешируется или для нее дополнительно проверяются референсы.

Comment: @KoVadim,заменил картинку(на черную-тоже 1х1)-не грузиться в письмо она. в .htaccess такое RewriteRule ^upload/logo_(.+\.png)$ task.php?id=$1. почему когда тестировал с бесплатника-нормально все было?ничего не понимаю...

Comment: это все очень похоже на кеширование.